# Deleting multiple items in checkboxes at once using REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I'm trying to delete multiple items at once for checkboxes in REACT, but the code does not seem to delete the items being checked.**

Here's my approach to doing this. I made a function in tasks.jsx file
called add_ids_to_be_deleted to append the id that was being checked
in the checkbox to an array of ids to be deleted called list_of_ids.
This function is called in the child component in priorityLists.jsx.
When the user clicks the delete button, I created a useEffect to
filter out all the items in toDo whose ids are not included in the ids
to be deleted.

**The problem is it keeps deleting the last item whenever I check a checkbox regardless of the order.**

For example, I add 3 checkboxes and
check the first checkbox to delete it. Instead of the first checkbox
being deleted, the last item is deleted even though it wasn't being
checked.

**tasks.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Delete, Refresh, Add } from '../components/Actions';
import { Header } from '../components/Header';
import ToDoList from '../components/TaskList';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faPlus, faTrash } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function Task() {
  const [toDo, setToDo] = useState([]);
  const [idsToRefresh, setIdsToRefresh] = useState([]);
  const [list_of_Ids, setIds] = useState([]);
  const [filter_now, setFilterNow] = useState(false);

  function addToDos() {
    const id = uuidv4();
    setToDo(
      toDo.concat({
        _isKey: id,
        _checked: false,
        value: <ToDoList _onDelete={add_Ids_ToBe_Deleted} _key={id} />
      })
    );
    setIdsToRefresh(idsToRefresh.concat(id));
  }

  function switchNow() {
    if (!filter_now) {
      setFilterNow(true);
    } else {
      setFilterNow(false);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (toDo[0] !== undefined) {
      setToDo(
        toDo.filter(item => {
          return !list_of_Ids.includes(item._isKey);
        })
      );
    }
  }, [filter_now]);

  function add_Ids_ToBe_Deleted(_id_ToBe_Deleted) {
    setIds(item => [...item, _id_ToBe_Deleted]);
  }

  function refresh() {
    setToDo(
      toDo.filter(item => {
        return !idsToRefresh.includes(item._isKey);
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="main-content">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row underline">
          <div className="col">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-3 pt-2">
                <Refresh _refresh={refresh} />
              </div>

              <div className="col-6 text-center">
                <Header header={'Tasks'} />
              </div>

              <div className="col-3 pt-2">
                <button className="float-right">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    onClick={switchNow}
                    icon={faTrash}
                    size="2x"
                  />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            {toDo.map(item => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>{item.value}</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col pr-4">
            <button onClick={addToDos} className="float-right" name="add">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} size="2x" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Task;
```

**Tasklist.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { PriorityLists } from '../components/PriorityLists';
import { Priority } from './Actions';

function ToDoList(props) {
  return (
    <PriorityLists
      _onDelete={props._onDelete}
      keys={props._key}
      name="toDoList"
    >
      <Priority />
    </PriorityLists>
  );
}

export default ToDoList;
```

**Prioritylists.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Priority } from './Actions';

function PriorityLists(props) {
  return (
    <form>
      <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <div className="input-group-prepend">
          <div className="input-group-text">
            <input
              is_checked={false}
              unique_Key={props.keys}
              onClick={e =>
                props._onDelete(
                  e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('unique_Key').value
                )
              }
              id="check-item"
              type="checkbox"
              aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" name={props.name}></textarea>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export { PriorityLists };
```

Comment: it will be easy if you have provide the code as project in stackbltiz